# Permissions and SVN Updates on Windows Server 2008: same folder & SVN account, different Active Directory users

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, windows-server-2008

We're experiencing strange permission issues with SVN after switching from Windows Server 2003 to Server 2008.

On our standard build box there is a folder (`C:\SVN_Code_Folder`) which AD_User_A associates with a SVN repository using SVN_User and TortoiseSVN 1.7.6

When using Windows 2003, when AD_User_B logs into the box and tries to Update, Switch, Merge the SVN_Code_Folder with SVN_User, the command is executed.

It Windows 2008, it fails with the message:

> Command: Update
>   Error: Working copy 'C:\jboss-4.2.3.GA\server\New folder' locked
>   Error: sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
>   Error: sqlite: attempt to write a readonly database
>   Completed!

Attempting to unlock the file, which was never locked, via the context menu is met with the following message:

> There's nothing to unlock.  No file has a lock in this working copy.

I've played with the permissions of the folder and I've discovered that giving "Domain Users" control over the folder fixes the issue, but I would prefer to not have such a broad permissions.  I've tried granting the same permissions to individual users and a SVN-group, but these too did not work.

What am I missing?
Is this an improper use of SVN?
Can 2 different Domain users update a folder using SVN without removing the .SVN file?

Answer (score 4):

For future reference...

I had this same problem with some WC's that I copied over to my new laptop's hard drive, from a file share on my old machine.

It turned out that the problem was solved by giving myself (as opposed to all domain users, or any other group) full control over the folder.

Comment: This solved the problem for me too (on Windows 2012 R2). I already had "Full Access" through a group and still got the error. After giving "Full Access" to my user too I the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the svn service user on the win2008 machine?
Does that user have local administrator privileges and also have permission to these folders on c:?
After changing anything restart the service.

Answer (score 0):

For me change folder permissions did't help, but I have update for several directories in a batch script so I solved this by

> cmd -> Run as administrator -> start update script